# Combining two Listviews into a single Listview with headers

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

How to combine two listviews separarted with headers in xamarin.forms . So far,I've got to know that I can use group Listviews to achieve this.But I'm not sure how to implement this.All of the sources implementing it through static data but in my case the Listview items are dynamic.

It is how implemented via static data.

```
List<GroupListModel> Groups = new List<GroupListModel>
            {
                new GroupListModel("list1","list1")
                {
                 new UserModel
                 {
                     FirstName = "list 1-1",
                     LastName= "12",
                 },
                },
                new GroupListModel("list2","list2")
                {
                    new UserModel
                    {
                        FirstName = "list2-1",
                        LastName= "1",
                    },
                    new UserModel
                    {
                        FirstName = "list2-2",
                        LastName= "2",
                    },
                    new UserModel
                    {
                        FirstName = "list2-3",
                        LastName= "3",
                    },
                    new UserModel
                    {
                        FirstName = "list 2-4",
                        LastName= "4",
                    },
                },
            };

            All = Groups;
```

and here is my grouplist model,

```
public class GroupListModel:List<UserModel>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public GroupListModel(string title, string shortName)
    {
        Title = title;
        ShortName = shortName;
    }

    public List<UserModel> Listofusers;

    public static List<GroupListModel> All { set; get; }
},
```

Now.What I want is the data in the list1 has to be dynamic i.e.,List1 listitems should contain a list of data returning from server calls.

I want something like this.
[I want a listview like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7uUe.png)

Can anyone please help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: are you trying to make an [expandable listview?](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-lNy3WHNMCCE/V2bVAh_VdhI/AAAAAAAABY0/LgDeaDGwg20sXeJOx0wwCbBg0ysYyyELwCLcB/s1600/Exp_Animated.gif)

Comment: @G.hakim ,no hakim

Comment: Can you show me what are you trying to achieve your question is not very clear

Comment: @G.hakim,I have edited my question can you please have a look

Comment: Will the headers be collapsible?

Comment: @G.hakim, No I don't want the headers to be collapsible

Comment: Okay i guess i can answer this give me some time

Answer (score 0):

Set `IsGroupingEnabled` to `true`.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding GroupList}"  IsGroupingEnabled="True">
    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="5">
                   <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                   <Label Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```